# Always get a neutral normal map

Tags: mesh, normals, baking, normal-map, multiresolution

I have multiresed my mesh and then applied the modifier. No matter I do I always get a neutral normal map while baking.
But if I bake without applying I get a kinda normal map but yet the mesh shape on it is kinda weak [image]

Comment: Hello please share your file (only keep the useful objects): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: The normal map file you mean ?

Comment: the file with the object you're trying to bake

Comment: Keep in mind that when you bake a multires you need to bring back its Level Viewport to 0, otherwise it won't bake anything